# How to rotate UV around a given point using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, uv, vector

First I want to say I have done the reading on this one, but I am still lost. I have seen some other posts here regarding how to handle this [using 3D matrices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106648/set-matrix-rotation-value-not-add-to-it/106718#106718), posts on the main Stack Overflow site for handling [2D Vector rotation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620745/c-rotating-a-vector-around-a-certain-point), and I have some chapters of [this book](https://www.manning.com/books/math-for-programmers?gclid=Cj0KCQjw1ouKBhC5ARIsAHXNMI8YszaTEUDo7ikNJba7kAz1BBrvTyUVXSmhdevfwD4mwMZEN80KgeAaAiS1EALw_wcB) that covers rotating points using Python. From all that research, I have been able to properly rotate around the origin (0,0 - Bottom Left). Code for that below:

```py
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
from math import pi, sin, cos, atan2, hypot 

def to_cartesian(polar_coord):
    length, angle = polar_coord.x, polar_coord.y
    return Vector((length * cos(angle), length * sin(angle)))
    
def to_polar(vector):
    x, y = vector[0], vector[1]
    angle = atan2(y, x)
    return Vector((hypot(x, y), angle))


def Rotate2D(v, r):
    v_polar = to_polar(v)
    v_rotated_polar = Vector((v_polar.x, v_polar.y + r))
    v_prime = to_cartesian(v_rotated_polar)
    return v_prime

# then call Rotate2D() on all vertices within the UVMap.
def RotateUV(uvMap, rotation, pivot):
    for uvIndex in range(len(uvMap.data)):
        uvMap.data[uvIndex].uv = Rotate2D(uvMap.data[uvIndex].uv, rotation)
```

The above code when called on a given object, will rotate it around the point (0,0):[image: 45 Degree Turn]

When I have tried to implement the ideas given in the above response on StackOverflow, where you **subtract** the pivot from the given vector coordinate before you get the angles, then **add** them back at the end, I get strange results:

[image: 45 Degree Rotation around (0.5,0.5)]

The python implementation of the referenced C++ code:

```
# Assuming input coords are passed as Polar coords
def to_cartesian_pivot(coord, angle, pivot):
    x_rotated = ((coord.x - pivot.x) * cos(angle)) - ((coord.y - pivot.y) * sin(angle)) + pivot.x
    y_rotated = ((coord.x - pivot.x) * sin(angle)) - ((coord.y - pivot.y) * cos(angle)) + pivot.y
    return Vector((x_rotated, y_rotated))

def Rotate2D(v,p,r)
    v_polar = to_polar(v)
    v_rotated_polar = Vector((v_polar.x, v_polar.y + r))
    v_prime = to_cartesian_pivot(v_rotated_polar, r, p)
    return v_prime
```

I am unsure where exactly my algorithm is wrong. I think the issue must be in how I am handling the rotated coordinates. Either my order of operations is wrong, or I am giving it the wrong type of coordinate (Polar vs Cartesian?). If there is any clarification you need, let me know.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/213318/how-to-rotate-uv-and-preserve-the-correct-aspect-ratio